# Determining if Ancestry DNA results support Half Sibling relationship?

Tags: research-methods

Ancestry DNA results came back on my possible half sister. We're showing 1,329 cMs with 34 shared segments. All it indicated was we were "close relationship - 1st Cousins"
Tracing indicates a good possibility we are half siblings. Is the 1,329 on Ancestry enough to establish our relation or should we submit DNA samples to a lab for their analysis?

Comment: Very similar questions have been asked at least twice before. See the answer to https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/13929/possible-half-sibling-based-on-matching-centimorgans for more information.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  If you follow the advice in the duplicate and then are still stuck feel free to edit your question to indicate that and include precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck, then the community may be willing to re-open and answer your question.